# C++ Microsoft Speech Platform DTMF emulateRecognition Blocks Speech Recognition

Tags: c++, speech-recognition, sapi

I have an IVR application that can accept speech recognition and DTMF for use with VXML. The application was originally running on a Windows 2003 server as a service with (what looks like) SAPI 5.2 written in C++.

I have been tasked with updating this application to run on Windows 2012 server. To do that I have switched to using Microsoft Speech Platform 10.2 (version 11 wouldn't work at all). The voice recognition works when the service starts and the DTMF works all the time.

The issue arises when you try to use the speech recognition after DTMF has been used. Speech recognition will not work until the service is restarted. When I say will not work, the application recognizes no speech and therefore doesn't try to identify it. The DTMF continues to work.

I have narrowed the problem down to one line of code that calls out to ISpRecognizer::EmulateRecognition. If I comment this call out then the speech recognition continues to work but the DTMF doesn't process.

I can include code samples if desired but the application is rather large so just let me know what you would like to see.

Has anyone had similar issues?